# Congratulations to Robert Israel!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user, celebration

With Robert, we now have [two rows of 100k members](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) complete.
Thanks for all your contributions...

$\hskip2.3in$ [image]

Comment: And MSE is up to [two whole rows](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) of $100$K+!

Comment: Congrats indeed!

Comment: I foresaw that this would happen! (When the first page of Users showed his rep at 99,949...)  Congratulations on a lot of high quality contributions.

Comment: Congratulations. The answers of Robert Israel has 'surgical precision' and answer each question at the exact point of the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Congratulations for the landmark, Centurion!